# How to Roslaunch node in GDB?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) says it's possible to Roslauch nodes in gdb, but this doesn't apply to my case.

I launch the node in the following way:

```
  <node name="Multi_obj_qp_node" pkg="dumbo_Multi_obj_control" type="qp_multi_obj_control_node" cwd="node" respawn="false" output="screen"  launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb -d=$(find dumbo_Multi_obj_control)/ros/bin/ -e=qp_multi_obj_control_node" >
<rosparam command="load" file="$(find dumbo_Multi_obj_control)/config/Multi_obj_lp.yaml"/>
```

> But I got the following error:

```
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

Roslaunch got a 'No such file or directory' error while attempting to run:

`xterm -e gdb -d=/home/yuquan/myrepo/dam/ros/dumbo_apps/dumbo_Multi_obj_control/ros/bin/ -e=qp_multi_obj_control_node /home/yuquan/myrepo/dam/ros/dumbo_apps/dumbo_Multi_obj_control/ros/bin/qp_multi_obj_control_node __name:=Multi_obj_qp_node __log:=/home/yuquan/.ros/log/fa2d2a5c-2381-11e2-b6dc-0022150df8c3/Multi_obj_qp_node-5.log

Please make sure that all the executables in this command exist and have
executable permission. This is often caused by a bad launch-prefix.

> One of my friends says gdb works with a single node just like a usual executable. But in my case I need to launch yaml together. Could any one give me some suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47210/how-to-roslaunch-node-in-gdb?/) by [yuquan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2801/yuquan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

```
<node name="Multi_obj_qp_node"
    pkg="dumbo_Multi_obj_control" 
    type="qp_multi_obj_control_node"
    respawn="false" output="screen" 
    launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb --args" >
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find dumbo_Multi_obj_control)/config/Multi_obj_lp.yaml"/>
</node>
```

Also, you can ignore the "_DummyThread" error, it's an inconsequential error in Ubuntu's python distribution.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yuquan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2801/yuquan/) on 2012-11-03**:
Yes, It works! Great!